How to deploy Blazor Auto(both server and Client) Project?
I am using .net 8 Blazor Auto project where we get server and Client as separate web projects. When I publish it seems to be publishing two different locations.
I was thinking it would get merged together as a single deployment to single App service.

They are merged actually. For instance there are 2 projects in the solution MyProject (serverside) and MyProject.client (clientside).
You only need choose the "MyProject"(serverside) to publish. You will find the clientside files will be published to a "wwwroot" folder. So they are merged. You could check the "appsettings.json" in the wwwroot is from client project. When another appsettings in the publish root folder is from server project.
But if you choose the "MyProject.client" to publish. You will only have standalone client files.
